# Program to display a grid on screen

Tags: graphics, software-rec

Is there any program that can show/display grid lines on the screen.
I want use this grid as a ruler for web design and ....

Comment: Unclear what you're asking.  In ASCII, on terminal ?  Or graphically, in a GNOME desktop or somesuch ?

Comment: something like https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/the-grids/jgfgflhpelebngbkojdfjjekjnkgdcag

Comment: but for whole screen. not only web. GNOME desktop for exmaple